# How to ensure a colon after math-mode is always upright?

Tags: math-mode

A minor pet peeve (which may or may not agree with typographical good practices):
I dislike having a textual italic `:` right after math, especially an upright symbol like `]`, like this:
[image]

In many places, though, text is italic (usually due to `\emph`) and I use `:` after math.
I could tackle this:

1. always using `\textup{:}` instead of `:` after math;
2. never mixing italic text with math;
3. rephrasing my sentences such as to never place `:` after math;
4. use some LaTeX wizardry to ensure `:`-after-math is always upright.

I've been using strategy 1,
but after getting a bit annoyed with this and
also willing to find out if I could implement strategy 4 just for fun,
I came up with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter


\newcommand*{\replace@colon}{%
  % typeset an upright colon,
  % then ignore the next character, which is the italic colon
  \textup{:}\@gobble
}

\newcommand*{\colon@scan}{%
  \@ifnextchar:\replace@colon\relax
}

\everymath{\aftergroup\colon@scan}


\makeatother
\begin{document}
\itshape
$0.5 \in [0,1]$:
it works with \$!

\(0.5 \in [0,1]\):
doesn't work with \verb|\(|.

\[0.5 \in [0,1]\]:
doesn't work with \verb|\[|.

\begin{math}
  0.5 \in [0,1]
\end{math}:
doesn't work with \verb|\begin{math}|.

\end{document}
```

So this "hack" works only with the simplest math-then-`:`, which is `$...$:`, like this:
[image]

(No, I'd never use `\[...\]:`, but I think it would be nice to make the hack work even in this weird case)

I think the main reason I can't think of a fix is that I don't really understand "when" exactly the `\everymath` code happens;
is there a way to make my colon-hack always work?

**--EDIT--**
I also came up with this alternative "hack":

```
\newcommand{\realcolon}{}  % just ensure the name's available
\edef\realcolon{\char`:\relax}  % store the original meaning of ":"
\catcode`:=\active
\let:\realcolon
\newcommand*{\upcolon}{\textup{\realcolon}\global\let:\realcolon}
\newcommand*{\makecolonupright}{\global\let:\upcolon}
\everymath{\aftergroup\makecolonupright}
```

This approach:

- works with `$`
- works with `\(`
- doesn't work with `\[`
- works with `\begin{math}`

Comment: I'm quite surprised that the colon is upright when it's input as `$...$:`, outside the dollar signs.  I *know* it's upright if it's within the `$...:$`.  Are you sure you didn't accidentally type it inside?

Comment: ("no-hack" meaning no `\everymath` line)
colon-then-dollar and no-hack yields an upright but badly spaced colon.
colon-then-dollar and hack yields an upright but very badly spaced colon (because the `\@gobble` eats the next space).
dollar-then-colon and no-hack yields an italic colon (the essence of my pet peeve).
dollar-then-colon and hack yields an upright colon.

Comment: Long, long ago, it was proposed to define a "theorem" font with upright punctuation, including parens and other fences, as it would look better with math.  That's just a bit more than you are looking for.  Nice idea, but it never happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve each case by individual approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\colonscan{\futurelet\next\colonscanA}
\def\colonscanA{\ifx\next:\expandafter\colonscanB\fi}
\def\colonscanB#1{\textup{:}}
\def\colonscanE#1\ignorespaces\fi{#1\ignorespaces\fi\colonscan}
\everymath{\aftergroup\colonscan} % for cases $...$:
\addto\){\colonscan}              % for cases \(...\):
\addto\endmath{\colonscanE}       % for cases \end{math}:

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\itshape
$0.5 \in [0,1]$:
it works with \$!

\(0.5 \in [0,1]\):
it works with \verb|\(|.

\[0.5 \in [0,1]\]:
doesn't work with \verb|\[|.

\begin{math}
  0.5 \in [0,1]
\end{math}:
it works with \verb|\begin{math}|.

\end{document}
```

Comment: this `\addto` can be replaced by `\g@addto@macro` from the LaTeX kernel

Answer (score 5):

A colon in math mode will always appear upright, never slanted. To circumvent your issue, you can just put the colon *inside* an inline math mode chunk, like this:

`$0.5 \in [0,1]:$`

Comment: Although upright, it looks weird unless between braces like `$0.5 \in [0,1]{:}$`. I believe that's because colon in math-mode is mathbin (or was it mathrel?).
Typing `{:}$` is not much better IMO than `$\textup{:}` (even though it's shorter), specially because at first glance and due to syntax highlighting it looks like there's no textual punctuation, just math.
But it's an additional strategy, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You could define

```
\newcommand\upcolon{\textup{:}}
```

Possibly using `xspace` so as not to gobble trailing whitespace.

Comment: well, yes, that is what I called "strategy 1" in the post, minus 2 keystrokes (and using `\textup{:}` has the additional benefit of not gobbling any whitespace).

Comment: @DanielDiniz Of course you’re aware of `\textup`. I wondered if `\upcolon` would be less annoying to you. Another approach might be to set `:` active and redefine it to call an `\ifmmode` macro.

Answer (score 1):

(This is very similar to the snippet I posted in the **--EDIT--** part of the question)

As explained in (for example) "TeX by topic",
`\everymath` acts on inline math, whereas
`\everydisplay` acts on displayed math.
So it's possible to tweak the `:` after any math,
even though a colon after displayed math is probably a bad idea
(semantically and typographically).

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\realcolon}{}       % just ensure the name's available
\edef\realcolon{\char`:\relax}   % store the original meaning of colon
\NewCommandCopy\pickcolon\@firstoftwo
\catcode`:=\active
\def:{\pickcolon
  {\realcolon}
  {\textup{\realcolon}\global\let\pickcolon\@firstoftwo}%
}
\newcommand*{\makecolonupright}{\global\let\pickcolon\@secondoftwo}
% (the following explanations are from "TeX by topic" by Victor Eijkhout)
% \everymath<token parameter> token list inserted at the start of non-display math
% \aftergroup<token> save the next token for insertion after the current group
\everymath{\aftergroup\makecolonupright}
% erase/comment this next line to leave colons after displayed math untouched
\everydisplay{\aftergroup\makecolonupright}  
\makeatother
```

Caveat:
because this works by turning `:` into an active character and
changing its catcode, it
might be incompatible with packages that assume `:` is
an "other" symbol (catcode 12).